# Regex for complex string in comma separated list

Tags: regex

Good day all,

I've been fighting with this for the better part of the day and I can't seem to nail down this query.

Trying to come up with a regex that will go through a comma separated list of URLs and select all except the ones like this:

```
https://staticvalue.com/v3/__https://www.randomsite.com/__;!!Fjc1LPEtn8I!I_fRpN64qL1p3zCojqJHC0dSfh2jrinxfQ6h9Pscim9GpFzKqECpW2vaD6N7Xh1w$
```

*There should be 2 underscores between `v3/` and `https://www.randomsite.com`, then between `https://www.randomsite.com/` and `;!!` but it looks like the stackoverflow site is formatting the string so that they aren't visible.*

What the value being filtered out have in common

- 1st section starts with `https://staticvalue.com/v3/__`
- 2nd section is a HTTP or HTTPS website
- 3rd section is the character string `__;!!`
- 4th and final section is a 76 character string that always ends with `$`

Any regex doctors in the house? Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Which programming language/regex flavour are you using?

Comment: You say what they all have in common, but what are we separating them from?  Do any one of those criteria define a "bad" entry?  So any entry that starts with `https://staticvalue.com/v3/__` is "bad"?  Or must all the conditions be true in order for it to be considered "bad"?  Also, do you mind if the regex selects only the "bad" entries, or is it a requirement that is must select the inverse?  All of these details are important when constructing a regex.

Comment: Perhaps you can indicated what the regex is supposed to select vs what its not supposed to select, and having some examples would help e.g. "duck" passes but "duc/k" fails

Answer (score 0):

Well, someone who will know exactly how to help you would be someone who specializes in regex, but I leave here my noble contribution:

Don't use this regex, it's just for you to get an idea.

```
^/(https:\/\/staticvalue\.com\/v3\/__){1}(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})(__;!!){1}(.){76}\$$/gmi
```

My tests [here](https://regex101.com/r/xiiWFG/2/).